CSS grid scroll behavior horizontal and vertical inconsistent
According to the grid I set in CSS: when the screen becomes too small, the SVG area should get horizontal and vertical scroll bars. However: I only get a horizontal scrollbar. No vertical scrollbar. I have no clue as to why that is.


.header {
  grid-area: header;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  justify-self: center;
  /*horizontal alignment of the grid area*/
  align-self: center;
  /*vertical alignment of the grid area*/
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 30px auto 30px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "hmiTree svg" "footer footer";
}

.hmiTree {
  grid-area: hmiTree;
}

.svg {
  grid-area: svg;
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* display scroll-bars if screen becomes too small */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* display scroll-bars if screen becomes too small */
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  align-self: center;
  /*vertical alignment of the grid area*/
}
<div class="container">
  <div id="header" class="header">
    <p>SVG HMI</p>
  </div>
  <div id="navigationTree" class="hmiTree">
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="svg">
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="footer" class="footer">
    <button id="exportTagConfigButton">Export tag configuration</button>
    <button id="exportConfigButton">Export configuration</button>
  </div>
</div>




Edit: Why overflow-y is not working?
overflow-x and overflow-y behave differently because block elements' auto sizing is different for width and height. The width respects to the screen width, but the height respects to the total height of its contents. Therefore, some restrictions need to be applied to the height, otherwise the container block's height will always grow to be enough to fit all child contents, and so overflow-y will never occur. You can observe this with a simpler example:


.item {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
Anchor point
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h1>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h1>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h1>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h1>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h1>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h1>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h1>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h1>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h1>
  </div>
</div>




The height of the grid track that contains the SVG is auto since you set grid-template-rows: 30px auto 30px, hence the grid height will grow along with it. As mentioned above, you'll need to somehow restrict its height to have the overflow-y work.
Depending on your need you can either have .svg's height follow the height of the left column, or restrict some height to not exceed the screen size.

Restrict height to fit screen size
One way is to restrict the height of the .svg container to be between (100% and 100vh - remaining rows' height)
max-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
min-height: 100%;



.header {
  grid-area: header;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.container {
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 30px auto 30px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "hmiTree svg" "footer footer";
}

.hmiTree {
  grid-area: hmiTree;
}

.svg {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  min-height: 100%;
  grid-area: svg;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  align-self: center;
}
<div class="container">
  <div id="header" class="header">
    <p>SVG HMI</p>
  </div>
  <div id="navigationTree" class="hmiTree">
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="svg">
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>

  </div>
  <div id="footer" class="footer">
    <button id="exportTagConfigButton">Export tag configuration</button>
    <button id="exportConfigButton">Export configuration</button>
  </div>
</div>



Follow the height of the left column
You can set contain:size on the .svg container so that its height does not depend on its child SVG's height. See Temani Afif's awesome answer.
contain:size;



.header {
  grid-area: header;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 30px auto 30px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "hmiTree svg" "footer footer";
}

.hmiTree {
  grid-area: hmiTree;
}

.svg {
  contain: size;
  grid-area: svg;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  align-self: center;
  /*vertical alignment of the grid area*/
}
<div class="container">
  <div id="header" class="header">
    <p>SVG HMI</p>
  </div>
  <div id="navigationTree" class="hmiTree">
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="svg">
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>
    <h1>SOMESVG</h1>

  </div>
  <div id="footer" class="footer">
    <button id="exportTagConfigButton">Export tag configuration</button>
    <button id="exportConfigButton">Export configuration</button>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks for this reply, but I don't understand what you are trying to say. What I observed is different behavior in horizontal and vertical scroll bars while I would expect equal behavior. The code is symmetrical but the behaviour is asymmetrical.

It is simply because div width grows with screen size, but height doesn't so you'll need to specify the height as mentioned above. I've added some explanation in the answer.
